# How to find the maximum number of associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Accounts` and `Users`. Account `has_many :users` and User `belongs_to :account`.

What I'm trying to find out is the maximum number of users any single account has.

So, it would need to cycle through all the accounts, sum up the users for each account and return the user count for each account or, ideally, just the maximum user count it found in all of them.

Running Rails 4.0.12 and Ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: show the structure..and code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do:

```
Account.all.each_with_object({}) do |account, hash|
  hash[account.name] = account.users.count
end
```

That will return a hash of all accounts with their user totals as their value.

Something like:

```
=> { "Account1" => 200, "Account2" => 50 }
```

To sort it, do something like

```
results = Account.all.each_with_object({}) do |account, hash|
  hash[account.name] = account.users.count
end

sorted = results.sort_by { |acc, ct| ct }.reverse
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to sort the output by total count?

Comment: What @SimoneCarletti said. :) Seems somebody is just down voting all the answers. Really appreciate it, @Anthony!

Comment: Since only the maximum is needed, consider using [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by), which is more efficient than sorting the array.

Answer (score 8):

You can loop all the accounts, and perform a count, but it is very inefficient. Use a `JOIN` and `COUNT`.

```
result = Account.select('accounts.id, COUNT(users.id)').joins(:users).group('accounts.id')
```

The result will be

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Account id: 6>, #<Account id: 4>, #<Account id: 5>, #<Account id: 1>, #<Account id: 3>]>
```

and each item `attributes` are

```
{"id"=>1, "count"=>1}
```

Therefore if you take each `result` you have

```
results.each do |result|
  result.id
  # => the account id
  result.count
  # => the count of user per account
end
```

To have all in one hash

```
results.inject({}) do |hash, result|
  hash.merge!(result.id => result.count)
end
```

Comment: Very nice, Simone. A detail: at the end, isn't what you have the same as  `hash.merge!(result)`? Readers: `Hash#merge!` and  `Hash#update` are equivalent.

Comment: @CarySwoveland no result is kind of AR object. So you need to do as Simone did here.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @Arup. I often get burned when I venture into Rails territory. Rails is on my to-list; I'll get to it one day.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making a query for each account, I would suggest updating the query to do group by your field, and order by the count:

```
User.group('account_id').order('count_all DESC').limit(1).count
```

Comment: You should add `DESC` parameter to `order` constraint and all would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `:counter_cache`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, counter_cache: count_of_users
end
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: This is the best solution if it's not a one-off query or something that doesn't get checked often.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 ..
 def self.max_number_of_users
   all.map {|a| a.users.count}.max
 end
 ..
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the maximum number of records that the association have (so you know how many columns to plan for in say a spreadsheet), you can do this in one line:

```
Account.select('accounts.id, COUNT(users.id) as num').left_outer_joins(:users).group('accounts.id').map{|x| x[:num]}.max
```