# Better Where Conditions With Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application, I'm doing lots of where queries to count on models. Here is the code:

```
@examination.cities.includes(:translations).each do |city|
  Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, payment_status: true, examination_id: @examination.id).count
  Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, payment_status: false, examination_id: @examination.id).count
  Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, examination_id: @examination.id).count

  @examination.exam_languages.each do |exam_language|
    Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, language_preference: exam_language.id, examination_id: @examination.id).count
  end
end
```

The problem is, this code is generating too much SQL queries and it seems like unefficient. Is there a better approach, better way to handle this?

Comment: The `count` operations's result do not been stored in any variable. What's the reason for this? And the second block don't closes. Paste correct code to understand what are you trying to do would be better.

Comment: I edited the code. I might hold count operations results in a variable but does it reduces the number of SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by extracting out the various count queries inside the loops, and leverage the SQL language to perform the count with a single query.

For instance, if you take this loop

```
@examination.exam_languages.each do |exam_language|
    Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, language_preference: exam_language.id, examination_id: @examination.id).count
end
```

and you apply the principle I [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048588/123527), you can execute the count per language in a single query.

Other queries cannot be easily reduced with a single SQL statement. For instance

```
Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, payment_status: true, examination_id: @examination.id).count
Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, payment_status: false, examination_id: @examination.id).count
Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, examination_id: @examination.id).count
```

There are several possible approaches in this case. You can cache the query, so that it is performed only once in a range.

```
# the query is performed and cached for 1 minute
Rails.cache.fetch("queries/blabla/paid", expires_in: 1.minute) {
  Participation.where(exam_center_preference: city.id, payment_status: true, examination_id: @examination.id).count
}
```

Ideally, you should hide this complexity outside the controllers. Chaining a lot of ActiveRecord scopes in a controller it's definitely not a reusable approach. It also limit the ability to properly test the query.

Without mentioning when you start mixing your queries with other layers, such as a cache layer. You can consider [one of these patterns](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) to decompose your active record chains into reusable objects.